# Typescript: esnext compiler option destroys es6 import from external lib

Tags: typescript, node-modules

When setting ether the `module` or `target` property of the compiler options to esnext (id like to use `import("example")` statements), es6 import statements stop working for `npm install`ed librarys (local modules sill work: e.g. `"./test.ts"`).

So this `import * as asd from "testmodule";` throws `cannot find module 'testmodule'`. However omitting both properies makes it work. Why is this and what es standard should I use to keep `import("example")` and `import * as asd from "testmodule";` statements?

---

Here is my full tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

TLDR: When `"module"` is anything aside from `"commonjs"` you need to explicitly specifiy a `"moduleResolution"` value of `"node"` for this to work. Setting `"commonjs"`for`"module"` does so implicitly.

As this is by no means obvious, I strongly encourage explicitly specifying `"moduleResolution"` whenever specifying `"module"`.

I strongly recommend that you always specify the output module format explicitly.

Additionally, despite the names of certain options, `"target"` and `"module"` are independent and orthogonal. They mean very different things and must not be confused.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "esnext", // this isn't relevant
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

`"commonjs"` is an *output* module format. ESNext dynamic `import(...)` statements are a transpiled into the output module format just like other module syntax such as ES2015 `import` and `export` statements.

When you specify `--module esnext`, you are telling TypeScript not to transpile any module syntax at all. That's the point of `--module` it specifies the output module format, not the source module format.

Comment: I know it's late, but do you still remember where do you get this from ? 
I had fixed the same problem with my code, thanks to your explanation

Comment: Where do I get what from?