# How to import a function from NPM library without changing base configuration of Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using the following package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/macos-release

Here is my code:

```
import macosRelease from 'macos-release';

import { asyncExec } from '../../helpers/os-util';
import OsReleaseService from './os-release.service';

export default class OsReleaseDarwinController extends OsReleaseService {
    protected async getReleaseImpl() {
        const releaseName = macosRelease().name;

        const [releaseVersion, osBuildVersion] = await Promise.all([
            asyncExec('/usr/bin/sw_vers -productVersion').catch(() => ''),
            asyncExec('/usr/bin/sw_vers -buildVersion').catch(() => ''),
        ]);

        return `MacOS ${releaseName} ${releaseVersion} ${osBuildVersion}`;
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get an error:

```
......../macos-release/index.js:1
import os from 'node:os';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Here is my tsconfig:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

Is it possible to overcome this error without changing any configuration? I don't want to change tsconfig file nor package.json file

Comment: Why not just use common JS `const require ... ` syntax

Comment: @DOZBORNE How so. You want me to use `require` instead of `import`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this lib doesn't support common js. It seems like a pretty small lib, so maybe you could either create your own implementation or use a larger package

Comment: I don't even have this line in the code. It's from the package itself

Comment: my apologies. i didn't read that initially

Comment: potentially this might help as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383049/typescript-esnext-compiler-option-destroys-es6-import-from-external-lib/57383664#57383664

Comment: this would be the solution here @SeydouDoumbia

Comment: How so? Look at my `tsconfig.json` config file. I did provide all said in the provided thread

Comment: You're module is still set to `module: "commonjs"` The library you are trying to use isn't backwards compatible with older versions of node. So you would either have to convert to using "esnext" syntax or either write your own modified version of the package using commonJs syntax